# Run a sorted with permission

Tags: javascript, next.js

I created a site (dashboard) with NextJs which allows a Discord user to connect with his account. So I was able to recover the different guilds of the user but I would like to sort them to keep only the one where he has (at least) the MANAGE_GUILD perm or if he is the owner of the guilds.

I started to create a function to sort the guilds but it doesn't seem to work

```
export function guildsperm(guilds) {
  guilds.map((guilds) => {
    if (guilds.owner === true) {
      return guilds;
    } else if (guilds.permissions <= 0x0000000020) {
      return guilds;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

The doc : https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to check for the permissions is not to operate on them with "<.>,=" but rather with bitwise operators, as described in your docs!

For example, your specific case should be to change

```
else if (guilds.permissions <= 0x0000000020)
```

into

```
else if (guilds.permissions & 0x0000000020 == 0x0000000020)
```

Try it out and let us know if it works.

Comment: Yes thank you it works, I just edit like this :
```else if (guilds.permissions & +(0x0000000020 == 0x0000000020))```
otherwise it gave me a little syntax error